# How to email multiple doclinks of those who are my direct reports in the view?

Tags: email, view, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a question. For example there is one view and 10 documents are in that view. Out of all those documents, 8 of them I should be the recipient of the email (based on the field value which is my email address).

Now, what I want to happen is that I will be receiving only one email for all those 8 documents, and in that email I there will be 8 doclinks.

Is that possible?

'Cause currently I am getting 8 emails and for each email, there is one doclink. Thanks in advance for those who can help me.

```
Dim s As NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim i As Integer
Dim view As NotesView

Set s = New NotesSession
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.GetView("View")
Set doc = New NotesDocument(db)
Dim addresses As NotesName
i=0
Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
While Not(doc Is Nothing)
    Set addresses = New NotesName(doc.Manager(0)) 
    If addresses.abbreviated = "" Then
        i = i + 1
    Else 
        doc.SendTo = addresses.abbreviated
        doc.Form = "Memo"
        Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(doc, "Body")
        Call rtitem.AppendText("Balance")
        Call rtitem.appenddoclink(doc, "Link")
        doc.Send (True)
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show your code, then we can show you, where it is wrong

Comment: Hi @TorstenLink I have placed my code. Hope you can check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Thorsten said, it can be done. There are a couple of ways to handle this, depending on how flexible and future proof you want it, and how "clean" of a solution you want. 
Let's say you have 10 documents, 8 with your email and 2 with a different user's email. I assume you want to send one mail to you with 8 doc links and one to the other person with 2 doc links.

The way I would do it is to create a class. That class would contain a list of NotesDocuments (and a method to add documents to the list):

```
Class DocData
Public docs List As NotesDocument

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub Add(doc as NotesDocument)
    Set docs(doc.UniversalID) = doc
End Sub
End Class
```

In your main code, you have a list of DocData objects, one per mail recipient:

```
Dim docs List As DocData
```

You now loop through the view or the document collection you have. You check the email address for each document and if there isn't a list item for that address, you create it and add the document to it. If it already exists, just add the document:

```
email = doc.GetItemValue("EmailAddress")(0)
If !IsElement(docs(email)) Then
    Set docs(email) = New DocData()
End If
Call docs(email).Add(doc)
```

When all documents have been processed, you should have a list with one item per mail recipient, and you can loop through the list, build one email per item and populate it with doc links for all the documents in the list in the object.

For performance reasons, if you plan to have this working on larger views with more documents, I woudl suggest that you put the email address in one of the columns, and then use view entries to loop though the documents, and ColumnValues() to read the email address.
I wrote about it here: http://blog.texasswede.com/re-using-lotusscript-lists-to-increase-performance/

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be slightly modified to only send one mail:

```
Dim s As NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim i As Integer
Dim view As NotesView

Set s = New NotesSession
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.GetView("View")
Set doc = New NotesDocument(db)
Dim addresses As NotesName
i=0
'- prepare mail
doc.Form = "Memo"
Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(doc, "Body")
Call rtitem.AppendText("Balance")

Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
While Not(doc Is Nothing)
    Set addresses = New NotesName(doc.Manager(0)) 
    If addresses.abbreviated = "" Then
        i = i + 1
    Else 
        '- Set recipient
        If not doc.HasItem( "SendTo" ) then
            doc.SendTo = addresses.abbreviated
        End If
        '- Append descriptive text, link and new line
        Call rtitem.appendtext(doc.Subject(0) & "  " )
        Call rtitem.appenddoclink(doc, "Link")
        Call rtitem.addnewline(1)
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
'- send mail
Call doc.Send (True)
```

with that code the mail is first prepared, then a doclink is added for every document, and in the end the mail is sent.

Comment: I'm getting object variable not set at this part:
doc.SendTo = addresses.abbreviated